# Put result into session variables

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have the following:

```
$res = $backend->user_login($data);
```

When I do:

```
print_r($res); die();
```

I have:

```
Array ( [ID] => 4cf79960693054282e58eedb [phone-id] =>email@email.com [phone-type] => web )
```

Now I have to put each of the 3 results  in a session variable, so I will end up with 3 session variables containig ID, phone-id and phone-type.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
foreach($res as $name => $var) {
   $_SESSION[$name] = $var;
}
```

Comment: And make sure you use `session_start()`.

Comment: Looks great, how can I see or print $_SESSION[$name] so I can see that is correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you print_r($_SESSION) or var_dump($_SESSION) you can see what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way is:

```
$_SESSION['myRes'] = serialize($res);
```

Then recover it by this code:

```
$res = unserialize($_SESSION['myRes']);
```